# Error al usar imagen base 64 como fondo de div

Tags: base64

Tengo una variable que contiene una imagen en base 64, me gustaría colocarla como fondo en un div. Esto es lo que me ha  funcionado.

$(".modal-header").css('background-image' , 'url(' +imagen+ ')' );

Este es el contenido de la variable imgConvenio.

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

Comment: me parece que te falta los apostrofes, intenta con **$('#fondoModal').html("<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,"+imgConvenio+"' />");**

Comment: Lo he intentado tal cual y nada...

Comment: Con jquery puedes ponerle y quitarle un class de CSS que prodia ser por ejemplo : .backgrounddiv {
    background-image: url(" data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgBJ  ... 
 RU5ErkJggg==");
}

Comment: Qué tal si primero lo pruebas, para verificar el base64, tienes muchas opciones para ello, te dejo un par https://jsfiddle.net/casiano/xadvz/ y tambien https://www.opinionatedgeek.com/codecs/base64decoder

Comment: Podrías subir el valor de **imgConvenio** me da curiosidad saber si ese es el problema

Comment: Gracias por contestar. No se exactamente a que te refieres, la imagen en base 64 es correcta, la estoy usando en otras funciones   y aparece bien la imagen. Este caso es el que no me funciona por algún motivo

Comment: El valor de la variable  seria data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEs el resto esta arriba en la descripción del error. Creo que el error esta en que estoy repitiendo  lo de  image/jpeg;base64

Comment: Si, es que probé con eso y también me dio error, pero lo hice en código duro, con lo cual si debería funcionar, por eso te sugerí que primero pruebes la imagen para saber si estaba bien.

Comment: si puedes poner tu imàgen en base64 podrìamos descartar que haya un problema con la imàgen, ocmo que traiga explicitamente `base64` por ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear un objeto de tipo imagen y hacerle append

```
var imagen = new Image();
imagen.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD...';
document.body.appendChild(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que dice el error:

```
GET data:image/jpeg;base64,data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJ
```

Estás pasando al src dos veces la cabecera **data:image/jpeg;base64**, puede que ya esté presente en imgConvenio y cuando hacés:

```
<img src=data:image/jpeg;base64,"+imgConvenio+"/>
```

La estés agregando nuevamente generando el error.

Answer (score 0):

El origen (`source`) de la imagen que utilizas, está mal formado.

Según el error que presentas, tiene varias definiciones de formato y tipo (`data:image/jpeg;base64,`), y solo debería tener una, creo que tu variable `imgConvenio` ya contiene la definición al principio.

También, según el error, la cadena en `base64`, está mal formada y tiene un caracter `/` que provoca que no se traduzca a una imagen válida.

Solucionando esto, tu origen quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
data:mage/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJR.....ABRRRQAUUUUAf//Z
```

Para poner ese origen como fondo de un div, puedes utilizar CSS de la siguiente manera:

```
div{
    background-image: url("data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJR.....ABRRRQAUUUUAf//Z");
}
```

O con jQuery:

```
$('#fondoModal').css('backgroundImage', 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJR.....ABRRRQAUUUUAf//Z');
```